# Countdown Timer android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

Good day guys, please am building a soccer prediction app, and I want to show countdown to the match time. Once the game starts I call another function, but I cant get the countdown right.

Here is what have tried:

```
public void onSuccess(String response) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        userid.setText("Welcome: "+ usermail);
        hometeam.setText(json.getString("Home_Team"));
        awayteam.setText(json.getString("Away_Team"));
        home_logo.setImageUrl(url+json.getString("Home_Logo"));
        away_logo.setImageUrl(url+json.getString("Away_Logo"));
        game_id.setText(json.getString("ID"));
        match_date.setText(json.getString("Date")+" "+json.getString("Time"));

        //month.setText(json.getInt(name))
        SimpleDateFormat mdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date m_date= (Date) match_date.getText();
        CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(m_date.getTime(), 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("tick","clocks ticks");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }.start();  
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But once I run the app, it crashes. It was working fine until I added the countdown function. date and time comes back in this format. `"2013-12-23 20:00:00"`. Thanks.

Comment: could you please add a logcat to your answer

Comment: hii, the logcat says java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.date. Guess on the line where am retrieving the date and time from the database. Thanks

Comment: Don't guess, what line number does it give, and what is that line? Why is there mdate and m_date? Why call getText()? The logcat is your guide and is explicitly telling you want is wrong. We need it and the specific lines of code it is highlighting!

Answer (score 1):

Without a Logcat I cannot tell if there are multiple things wrong, or what exactly is happening.

[From the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html)

`getTime();`

returns a `Long`, the number of milliseconds since last Unix Epoch (1st Jan 1970). This will be a large number like *1387233645* or such.

[See here for Wikipedia article on Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch)

The constructor for the CountdownTimer is in the form

`CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)`

getTime() is returning the milliseconds since 01/01/1970 not millis in the future.

For an example, try a 30 second timer with default values: [Also from Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {       
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {          
   mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);      
}       

public void onFinish() {         
   mTextField.setText("done!");    
}   
}.start();
```

Comment: Thanks @RossC, but is there another way to countdown to the fixture date and time? The main reason for this is to remove the match once it has started. so people wont be able to predict again.

Comment: Well you have how many milliseconds that have passed since 01/01/1970 and you can tell how many milliseconds will have passed since 01/01/1970 and when the match starts... The difference between the two numbers is how many milliseconds in the future you will be! ie getTime() is now, and the time of the match. The 'time in the future paramater' will be match time minus current time! I'm saying do it for the preset 30 seconds first, then work on your variables, you have one (getTime) already! You can set the date time and getTime for the other! They're both numbers so it'll be arithmatic after!

Comment: ,Thanks but i don't understand all you wrote.. Please can you help write something. My date and time comes back in this format (2013-12-23 20:00:00). Thanks

Comment: You have mdate and m_date, why is this? I think you are getting your variables mixed up and one is returning milliseconds (m_date) and the other is a simple date format (mdate) which is the 2013-12-23 etc one. Clear all that code out and start again. You need 2 dates. matchDate and nowDate let's say, get rid of the underscore and stick to naming convention. nowDate is simply a getTime() call, and the match date is the date of the match which you can set() in Date, and then matchDate minus nowDate = timeInTheFuture, so you can have a new CountDownTimer(timeInTheFuture, 1000);